# В главной станице как реализовать отображение двух страниц Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, вёрстка, cms

Привет всем, хочу реализовать на сайт в формате лендинг пейдж, как сделать так, что бы на главной странице отобразился материал например с 2-х или 3-х страниц одновременно? Я пытался искать какие-то шоткоды на эту тему, но не нашел. Может у вас есть какие-то варианты?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Давно уже написал короткий шорткод для таких целей.

```
 function block_shortcode( $atts ) {
     $p = get_page_by_title($atts['title']);
     if ( function_exists('icl_object_id') ) {
         $id = icl_object_id( $p->ID, 'post', true );
         $p = get_post($id);
     }
     return do_shortcode($p->post_content);
 }
add_shortcode('block', 'block_shortcode');
```

Внутри if с проверкой icl_object_id - это для WPML. Можно эти 4 строчки убрать, если WPML не установлен, но функция и так работает корректно.

Использование:

```
[block title="Моя страница"]
```

Comment: Разобрался, работает!