# Как поставить другие разделы внутри страницы записи?

Tags: wordpress, page

Внутри страницы записы поставить элементы главной страницы. Пробовал несколько вариантов , не получилось. Как на этой странице(http://moreair.co/work/autonomous/). 
Во вложении показано.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Что именно с главной страницы надо вывести? `Пробовал несколько вариантов , не получилось` пример кода, с которым не получилось тоже не помешал бы

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/688453/220220

Comment: например , внутри страницы записи есть текст и фото , перед футером хочу поставить другие записи , или еще посмотреть записи

Comment: зайдите на сайт moreair.co , и нажмите на любой раздел и там внутри страницы записи есть more work

Comment: @MR.Aki на самом деле - не важно текст это или фото. Важно - чем оно является в WP. Если это задается с помощью произвольного поля то нужно просто обратиться к странице по ее id и достать это произвольное поле из любого места сайта.

Comment: Выс походу не поняли что я хочу

Comment: Это не с помощью произвольного поля. Вопрос в том что как мне поставить тот код который отвечает за блоки записи. и как внутри записи поставить (Еще работы)